# event for combobox databinding complete?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox on a winform, and need to be able to call a method when the combobox's databinding is complete.  I am surprised to see that there is no DataBindingComplete event for the ComboBox control, like there is for the DataGridView.

How can I know when data binding is complete?  Is databinding done synchronously for comboboxes?  (i.e., if I have the following code, is it guaranteed that data binding will be complete when it hits the second line of code?)

```
myComboBox.DataSource = foo
SomeMethod()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be bound at that point? What have you tested to show where it's not the case?

Comment: Because the DataGridView has an OnDataBindingComplete event, I thought databinding was done asynchronously.  Also, in ASP.Net, pretty much all controls have an OnDataBound event, also making me think that databinding was asynchronous.  The combobox seemed inconsistent with other controls.  If databinding is done synchronously, why do we have these events?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class where you handle all the data access, then as the data is retrieved you can raise an event from that layer to the calling form you use to display your data.

[Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)

Comment: Yes, I know when my data is loaded from the DB.  What I want to know is when the combobox is databound (i.e., when have all the combobox items been created?).

Comment: If your data is done loading from it's source the items have been created. If your data comes in `async` like `WCF` does then they fill later and can be detected and bound in an `Asynchronous callback` method. Like I stated in my answer if you have a `DAL` then after you make the call to the database then you raise the event and pass the data - now you know the data has been returned.